# Is there anyway to repeat the biggest segment of continuous segment of repeat using php?

Tags: php, string, for-loop, longest-substring

I want to put the input like "RKKRRRRK" and try to get the output like largest continuous segment.. Suppose my input may be "RKKKR" then my program will display 'KKK' is the largest continuous segment.. and then it also display the count is 3..

I've already write the code for counting 'R' values.. now i want this program also... need help anyone help me.. thanks in advance.

Here the code:-

```
<?php

    function numberOfR($string1) 
    {

        for($i=0;$i <strlen($string1);$i++)
        {
            if($string1[$i]!='K') 
            {
                $count++;
            }
        }
        return $count;
    }
    $return_value= numberOfR("RKKRK");
    echo "R's count is:";
    echo $return_value;
?>
```

Comment: do you want *largest continuous segment* of any letter or of the K letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
    function getLongetSegment($string) {
        $currentSegmentChar='';
        $currentSegment="";
        $biggestSegment="";
        $current_length=0;
        $biggest_length=0;
        for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++) {
            $char = $string[$i];
                if($char != $currentSegmentChar || $currentSegmentChar == '') {
                    if($current_length >= $biggest_length) {
                        $biggestSegment = $currentSegment;
                        $biggest_length = $current_length;
                    }
                    $currentSegmentChar = $char;
                    $currentSegment = $char;
                    $current_length = 1;
                }
                elseif($currentSegmentChar != '') {
                    $currentSegment .= $char;
                    $current_length++;
                }
        }
        if($current_length >= $biggest_length) {
            $biggestSegment = $currentSegment;
        }
        return array("string" => $biggestSegment,"length" => $biggest_length);
    }   
    print_r(getLongetSegment("RKKRGGG"));
?>
```

Result: GGG

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match_all` over here as

```
preg_match_all('/(.)\1+/i','RKKRRRRK',$res);
usort($res[0],function($a,$b){
    return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
});
echo $res[0][0];
```

Comment: You are welcome. (_FYI If any of these answer helps you you can accept any of these answers or uovote an answer which really helps you._)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood this quite right. Something like this:

```
function maxCharSequece($string1) 
{
    $maxSeq = $seq = 0;
    $maxChar = $lastChar = null;

    for( $i = 0; $i < strlen($string1); $i++ )
    {
        $c = $string1[$i];

        if (!$lastChar) $lastChar = $c;

        if ( $lastChar == $c ){
            if ( ++$seq > $maxSeq ) $maxChar = $lastChar;
        }
        else {
            $maxSeq = $seq;
            $seq = 0;
        }
    }

    return $maxChar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace_callback to receive all continuous segments and select the longest

```
$sq = '';
preg_replace_callback('/(.)\1+/', 
                      function ($i) use (&$sq) { 
                        if(strlen($i[0]) > strlen($sq)) $sq = $i[0]; 
                      },  $str);    
echo  $sq . " " . strlen($sq);
```

Comment: Good One... At first I'm going to write that one